# Como filtrar solo un numero en python

Tags: python

Tengo este dataframe en python:

```
+------+-------+
|group | count |
+------+-------+
| A        10  |
| B         5  |
+--------------+
```

Y quiero seleccionar solo el dato 10 , es decir, hacer un filtro por "A" que lo haria de tal manera:

```
df[df["group"]=="A"]
```

Pero luego quiero asignar a una variable el 10

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Ago así `df.count[df["group"]=="A"]`?

Comment: Pero esto me daria el conteo de cuantas veces me aparece A, es decir,  1. Y yo lo que quiero obtener el valor de A que es 10, no?

Answer (score 1):

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"group": ["A", "B"], "count": [10, 5]})
resultado = int(df.loc[df["group"]=="A", "count"].values[0])
```

He asumido que quieres que la variable sea de tipo entero. Si no, no hagas el casting a `int`.